# Concatenate data from multiple Excel sheets into one Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Within an Excel workbook I have 5 specific worksheets (different names) that I want concatenate the data from into a different worksheet (master) within the same workbook. Simply taking the data from each sheet and appending it to the bottom of the data in the "Master" sheet. Also removing blank rows if possible. Is there a macro that can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  In general, questions here are to help debug things that are not working well, not write code for you from scratch.  Also, what exactly are you trying to do?  Are all of the worksheets the same format (i.e. the same columns)?

Comment: @hpf - Hi, I have searched the internet and tried a number of scripts that have all been unsuccessful. All sheets have exactly the same format. Basically I want to combine all the data from the 5 sheets into one. So 5 sheets with 200 rows of data on each, get combined into a Master sheet with 1,000 lines of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several choices.  If you only need to do this once, don't bother using a macro.  Simply go to each sheet, copy the rows, move to the master sheet, scroll down to the first empty row, and paste.

Assuming that you actually need a macro for this, something like this might work:

```
Sub CombineSheets()
  Dim Wksht As Worksheet, MasterSht As Worksheet, R As Integer

  Set MasterSht = Worksheets.Add
  R = 0

  For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not Wksht Is MasterSht Then
        Wksht.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=MasterSht.Cells(R + 1, 1)
        R = MasterSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End If
  Next Wksht
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks. This works however only copies one worksheet not all of them. How can I specify what worksheets I want it to copy?

Comment: Are you asking for multiple workbooks?  This script cycles through all of the worksheets in one workbook.

Comment: Hi @hpf. No, only to be performed in the same workbook. I created a "test" workbook with 3 sheets all with varying data. When running the code in the "test" workbook a new sheet is created (have added name) and data from only the first sheet is copied into it, as opposed to data from all sheets.